# Move code generated in <body> to <head>

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Have built a function on a video platform so it generate Facebook OG:Meta video data when generating embed code for each Video. The last problem is to get the Meta data up to the head from body

What i want is to wrap the generated meta data in "some code" and then rewrite it in  where i can place a code / string

There must exist a php or javascript function for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example I moved the DIVs from the body to the head, with JavaScript. I used DIVs to demonstrate the working. You can

[link: script demonstration@jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Mjwr/)

You should replace the DIV with META:

```
metaTAGs = document.getElementsByTagName( "DIV" );
```

Becomes:

```
metaTAGs = document.getElementsByTagName( "META" );
```

[link: Your script, fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Mjwr/1/)

Comment: Thanks, tested it out on jsfiddle with my embed code and it's work perfect++ !

Comment: Can't get it to work on my own websites.

Load mootols 1.4.5 en load the script right before closing </head> but can't get it to work, what am i missing out on ?

Comment: Please put the script at the end of body, or attach it to the body- or window-onload event, to guarantee that the body with all its meta elements are parsed, after which they can be moved.

Comment: Solved it but the problem is that it don't get executed when facebook crawls the page so need to solve that 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592102/execute-javascript-when-facebook-crawls-website

Comment: Alright you don't want to copy the delay function.. that was for (the visual red-disappear) test, my bad.

Comment: I don't think facebook will run any js while crawling website. I'd go with server-side generation.

Comment: I dunno anything about the FB context :P I just suggested this try, but you'll be right.