# Execute Javascript when Facebook crawls website

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I use javascript function below to move embed Facebook Meta data to head, This works fine for visitors but not when FB crawls the page, How can i execute this when Facebook crawling the page ?

```
function metaBodyToHead() {

    var head = document.head,
        metaTAGs = document.getElementsByTagName( "DIV" );

    for( var i = 0, ln = metaTAGs.length; i < ln; i++ ) {

        head.appendChild( metaTAGs[ i ].parentNode.removeChild( metaTAGs[ i ] ) );
    }
}

metaBodyToHead();
```

I need to get the meta data in head when facebook crawls the page

Test page: http://greenboxmedia.org/meta.html

Facebook debug: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.greenboxmedia.org%2Fmeta.html

Comment: Is there something prevents you just output them in the head the first place?

Comment: It’s part of the question he asked a few hours earlier, http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11590553/move-code-generated-in-body-to-head

Comment: Generating meta data for the Facebook bot is only possible with server side code. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431694/dynamic-generation-of-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags By the way you can detect whether a Facebook user or the Facebook bot is visiting your site.

Comment: It's for a video solution with several users and websites, The meta data is in the embed code so i must find a way to move it to head with something that i can embed in the generated embed code, is this impossible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i execute this when Facebook crawling the page ?

**Not at all**, of course.

Facebook’s scraper just looks at the HTML code of your page; it’s not a full-fledged “browser” that would execute any client site code.

You’ll have to put your OG meta data into the HTML code that get’s delivered when the URL is requested. That’s how it works.