# Update Facebook like parameters dynamically after loading

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, share

I have a website with pages that are changed dynamically - the page url has a parameter (its ending, i.e. bla.com/m.jsp**?code=1234**) and the page's **content**, **title** and **description** are set according to the 'code' parameter in the end of the url.

Now, I have in the page a Facebook Like/Share button and I need to set their parameters which I know only **after** the page was loaded. I tried to use javascript and set the meta tags:

```
var titleStr = document.title += " " + answerFromTheServer.fullname;
document.title = titleStr;
$("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", titleStr);
```

But it's not working...

How can I set those 3 parameters of the Share (content / description / title)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you generate the OG tags via JSP? That would make much more sense imho...

Comment: _“I tried to use javascript and set the meta tags […] But it's not working...”_ – [well _of course_ it isn’t.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592102/execute-javascript-when-facebook-crawls-website/11592192#11592192) The only way to set these parameters at the moment the share happens was the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0), but that is now deprecated. You _will have to_ generate HTML code that contains the correct meta information server-side.